# Session Validation/management Best Practice?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am working on IOS app using Swift3. I am getting sessionToken once user is authenticated. I want to check that if user is logged on or not on each time user put application on background and open it again. Where to handle these checks? Should I use AppDelegate.swift overridden methods to verify these things? Or It should be done somewhere else?

Also, I want to know how to handle in-activeness of user. How to logout automatically if user is not active(No touch event detected , both in active and background state of app).

Application Structure:
1. LoginViewController(Default landing screen)
2. HomeScreen->2.1 UserList

Answer (score 0):

You can take look at below two methods,

```
 func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

 // OR

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Lion has mentioned you can handle in both the functions. Completing the use case you requested.

Case 1: When app is being terminated. Handle in

```
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
}
```

case 2:

```
 func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

      //Start a timer to invoke a method and handle your session clear and local notification to inform user in that method.

    }
```

Invalidate the timer at

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
```

and

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
}
```

Hope this helps.